# xquery returning count for each node.. i rather want those as total count with loop

Tags: xquery, marklogic-corb

I am trying to return count of the keyword in xquery but it is sending count of each node in corb job. Can somebody please help

Below is the query that i am using on corb job

URIS MODULE

```
let $d1 := xs:date("2019-01-10")
let $t1 := xs:time("17:15:00")
let $d2 := xs:date("2019-01-16")
let $t2 := xs:time("22:39:00")
let $uris:= cts:uris((),(),
  cts:and-query((
    cts:element-range-query(xs:QName("meta:source"), "=", "CIRRUS", $CODEPOINT),
    cts:element-range-query(xs:QName("meta:modifiedDateTime"), ">=", 
    fn:dateTime($d1, $t1)),
    cts:element-range-query(xs:QName("meta:modifiedDateTime"), "<=", fn:dateTime($d2, $t2))
  ))
)
return (fn:count($uris), $uris)`
```

PROCESS MODULE

```
declare variable $URI as xs:string external;
let $URI := xdmp:estimate(cts:search(fn:doc(), cts:word-query("Cirrus")))
return $URI`
```

Comment: I don't know what your input and output do and I'm not familiar with the xdmp and cts extension functions, but I can tell you that you are using variables as if this were a low-level imperative language rather than a functional language, and this ain't gonna work. Use the `count()` function, with an argument that evaluates to a sequence containing the things you want to count. Don't attempt to modify the values of variables.

Comment: `xdmp:estimate(cts:search(fn:doc(), cts:word-query("Cirrus")))` will return the number of documents that have that word. Are you trying to count the number of occurrences of the word instead? Or do you want to iterate over each document that has this word and return the count of the number of occurrences in each doc?

Comment: Hi @MadsHansen this query returns count, I get that too but while running as corb job it is not giving me number of documents in one shot rather it processes one nodes after another and print the count for each node.

Comment: Could you update the question and post the code from your CORB process module?

Comment: hi @MadsHansen it is updated

Answer (score 1):

The process module is invoked for each of the URIs in the sequence returned from the URIs module. Each time the process module is invoked, it sets the value of the `$URI` variable for that execution.

The process module is not using the `$URI` variable as part of the execution. It is performing the same static estimate query, assigning that value to a similarly named variable called $URI, and then returning the same result for each execution.

If you want to count the occurrences of the word in each document, then you should use the `$URI` to load the document: `fn:doc($URI)` and then count how many `meta:source` elements have that word.

The process module was using "Cirrus", but the URIs query was searching for "CIRRUS", but it isn't clear what the $COLLATION was. Assuming that you want a case-insensitive evaluation, you can just `lower-case()` the value and test equality to "cirrus".

```
declare namespace meta = "whatever your namespace is"
declare variable $URI as xs:string external;
count(fn:doc($URI)//meta:source[lower-case(.) = "cirrus"])
```

Comment: Thanks @MadsHansen but with that I get many line of counts. When I run URI-MODULE query on ML console then I get lot lesser count. But with this I am getting way too many counts. It keeps printing 1. If this sum of 1 is equal to what I get in ML console then I am good.

Comment: If each of your documents will only have one of those elements, then there is no need to run this as a batch job. Simply execute the xdmp:estimate search. You can use the CORB ModuleExecutor class for that, or you could use the /v1/eval REST endpoint https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/POST/v1/eval